# Implementing RecordSet-like class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

*From the outset, let me state that I'm working with some older technology. I'd rather use Entity Framework, but I have to use what the client is using if I want to get paid.*

I am converting some old VB6/VBA code to C#. The VB code relies on `RecordSet`, which allow you to browse results of a query and also randomly make changes to the current row.

To duplicate this functionality in C#, I need to make use of `SqlDataAdapter`, `DataSet`/`DataTable` and `SqlCommandBuilder` classes. Since every single database object seems to implement `IDisposable`, the whole thing becomes a bit unwieldy and detracts from my main logic.

So I've tried to provide this same functionality in a single class that implements `IDisposable`. I would love some feedback on this class. My main concern is if I'm leaving anything out that could leave something not getting cleaned up, but would also love any ideas on how I might make the code better.

**RecordSet Class**

```
public class RecordSet : IDisposable
{
    protected SqlConnection Connection;
    protected bool OwnsConnection;
    protected SqlCommand Command;
    protected SqlDataAdapter Adapter;
    protected SqlCommandBuilder CommandBuilder;
    protected DataTable DataTable;

    protected int RowIndex;

    public RecordSet(string connectionString)
    {
        if (connectionString == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("connectionString");
        Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        OwnsConnection = true;
    }

    public RecordSet(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        if (connection == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("connection");
        Connection = connection;
        OwnsConnection = false;
    }

    ~RecordSet()
    {
        Debug.Assert(Connection == null);
        Debug.Assert(Command == null);
        Debug.Assert(Adapter == null);
        Debug.Assert(CommandBuilder == null);
        Debug.Assert(DataTable == null);
    }

    public void Open(string query, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        if (Disposed)
            throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot reuse RecordSet.");

        Command = new SqlCommand(query, Connection);
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
                Command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }
        Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Command);
        CommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(Adapter);
        DataTable = new DataTable();

        Adapter.Fill(DataTable);
        RowIndex = -1;
    }

    public bool Read()
    {
        if ((RowIndex + 1) < DataTable.Rows.Count)
        {
            RowIndex++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object this[string field]
    {
        get
        {
            return DataTable.Rows[RowIndex][field];
        }
        set
        {
            DataTable.Rows[RowIndex][field] = value;
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        Adapter.Update(DataTable);
    }

    #region IDisposable

    protected bool Disposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (Disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            if (OwnsConnection && Connection != null)
                Connection.Dispose();
            if (Command != null)
                Command.Dispose();
            if (Adapter != null)
                Adapter.Dispose();
            if (CommandBuilder != null)
                CommandBuilder.Dispose();
            if (DataTable != null)
                DataTable.Dispose();
            Connection = null;
            Command = null;
            Adapter = null;
            CommandBuilder = null;
            DataTable = null;
        }
        Disposed = true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Example Usage 1**

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE Id = @FirstValue OR Id = @SecondValue";

using (RecordSet recordset = new RecordSet(connectionString))
{
    recordset.Open(query, new SqlParameter("@FirstValue", 2), new SqlParameter("@SecondValue", 3));
    while (recordset.Read())
    {
        recordset["Value3"] = 123;
    }

    recordset.Update();
}
```

**Example Usage 2**

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE Id = @FirstValue OR Id = @SecondValue";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (RecordSet recordset = new RecordSet(connection))
{
    recordset.Open(query, new SqlParameter("@FirstValue", 4), new SqlParameter("@SecondValue", 5));
    while (recordset.Read())
    {
        recordset["Value3"] = 456;
    }

    recordset.Update();
}
```

I'm using SQL Server. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: I like the idea of transposing an ADODB recordset to C#... I'll try to take a moment to review your code later. So.. you know both VBA and C# huh... if you're ever looking for an open-source project to contribute to, [I know one that could use your help](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck)!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: Well, I used to know VB6 pretty good. (Used to write alternating columns for *Visual Basic Programmer's Journal*.) But that was a long time ago and I've forgotten some things. Don't have much extra time these days but will take a look at the GitHub project.

Comment: @Heslacher: Sorry, I've continued to work on the code and found a couple of mistakes. I've stopped editing the question now.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Feel free to post a follow-up question instead.

Comment: @Mast: What if someone follows the question and wants to see all the changes incorporated? I can't put that in a comment. And it doesn't belong in an answer. As long as I keep the original body of my question intact, what's wrong with appending the revised code?

Comment: @Mast: And leaving in a couple of typo-like mistakes in my original question also goes against the purpose of this forum. So now I have to field comments about typos?

Comment: The moment an answer appears, your code is done. If you want to make further adjustments and incorporate the answers provided, feel free to post a new question with both questions linking towards each other. That's how it should be done.

Comment: Post a new question with the final code? That makes no sense. Showing the results of all the suggestions and additional work is *not* a question. That's not how it should be done.

Comment: @JonathanWood the problem with "updates" is just that it won't be clear for late answerers which version should be reviewed. See the `In addition` paragraph of the posted link.

Comment: @Mast: I could not disagree more here. First of all, the updates were very narrow in scope and do not detract from the point of the question. Second, to append a revised version of the code for the benefit of anyone wanting to see it (and not for getting feedback on the revised code) benefits anyone reading the question. I understand that why-doesn't-my-code-work question should not have the code edited. That is very different. You seem to be missing the nuances here by treating the two cases as if they are the same.

Comment: @Mast: I had made it very clear which version was being reviewed. I put a divider and a bold header above it at the end of the rest of the question. I've seen this done all the time on stackoverflow. You are using a sledgehammer approach to moderating when there are nuances involved. The site allows us to edit things for a reason.

Comment: @Mast: Just delete the question. I cannot. You and I are clearly not going to agree. I don't want the question up any more.

Comment: If you disagree with the scope of this site, feel free to post a question on [Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com). That's where policy is discussed and changed (if required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructors

```
public RecordSet(string connectionString)
{
    if (connectionString == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException("connectionString");
    Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    OwnsConnection = true;
}

public RecordSet(SqlConnection connection)
{
    if (connection == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException("connection");
    Connection = connection;
    OwnsConnection = false;
}
```

I would not throw a `NullReferenceException` but an `ArgumentNullException`.  From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

> A NullReferenceException exception is thrown when you try to access a member on a type whose value is null.

[versus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

> An ArgumentNullException exception is thrown when a method is invoked and at least one of the passed arguments is null but should never be null.

What makes me wonder is what should happen if `connectionString` is empty or whitespace.

---

This looks strange to me as a reader of the code

```
public void Open(string query, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    if (Disposed)
        throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot reuse RecordSet.");
```

If one doesn't dispose the `RecordSet` it looks ok to use a different query and reuse the object. If you want to state that the object is disposed you should throw an [`ObjectDisposedException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception(v=vs.110).aspx) but you should throw it as well from every `public` method/property.

---

`CommandBuilder` isn't really used so you could just remove it.

---

Classlevel variables should be named using `camelCase` casing. `PascalCase` casing should be used for namespaces, classes, properties and methods.

---

I would like to encourage you to always use braces `{}` although they might be optional. Its a little bit more to type but the code looks more structured and is IMO easier to read. In addition it helps to prevent hidden and therfor hard to find bugs.

If you want to stick to not using them, its your decision, at least you are consistent in your style.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Looks like most things you found were minor (which is encouraging). I'll consider the overhead of checking `Disposed` in every method. I know I've seen classes that can't be re-used. Not sure the best way to approach that. I'm also concerned about what happens if they call `Open` more than once. As far as `SqlCommandBuilder`, it performs an important task with the adapter, and it also implements `IDisposable`. So although I'm pretty sure it's harmless to not dispose it, I decided to for completeness.

Comment: @JonathanWood And just what task does CommandBuilder perform?

Comment: @paparazzo creating the update commands used by the adapter based on the select query

Comment: @paparazzo: It automatically builds the InsertCommand, UpdateCommand, and/or DeleteCommand for the adapter.